# How to get the status of finger print is enabled or not in android settings?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I want to get the status of the fingerprint settings; that is, whether the fingerprint settings is enabled or not. Even I can get the following status like

```
fingerprintManagerCompat.isHardwareDetected()
fingerprintManagerCompat.hasEnrolledFingerprints()
```

Say example if a user has enrolled the fingerprint but disabled it. 
So how can I get the status fingerprint button is enabled or disabled in settings page?

Comment: _"Say example if a user has enrolled the fingerprint but disabled it."_ What do you mean by "disable it"? Are you talking about the case where the user has chosen not to use fingerprint for unlocking the device? That doesn't really have anything to do with your app.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose to don't understand correctly your question. But in the below, you can get a reference for your action. And if you told us with more specific details maybe someone can help you

```
    FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) { 
    // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication     
} else if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) { 
    // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with 
} else { 
    // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication 
}
```

I think you must check this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManagerCompat.html

**Edit #1 as you comment in below.**

isHardwareDetected() method must be provide to hardware functionality(enable or disable) and availability(exist or not) as in the description. That means this method must be returned hardware enable or disable state or hardware is existed or not existed. According to above if-else code block must still be acceptable for your requirement.

The first state is still acceptable for the check to your device's fingerprint functionality state.

[image]

Comment: Actually I can get the status of the hardware detected()and hasEnrolled(). But I can't take the status if finger print button in settings page